# Why are SOAP and GET disabled in asmx webservices by default?

Tags: asmx

I'm about to turn on the missing protocols for my asmx webservices.  They're already behind two layers of authentication and has a role checking attribute, so otherwise it is secure.

This [MS KB article explains GET and SOAP](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;819267) are disabled for asmx by default, while POST is enabled by default, but doesn't say why other than "security reasons."  Is this just superstition?  Why did they do that?  It seems that having POST enabled is just as insecure as having GET enabled.

I suppose this reduced the attack surface, but disabling everything until someone invokes the webservice by a particular protocol would be even more secure than leaving POST enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual link is [INFO: HTTP GET and HTTP POST Are Disabled by Default](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267) .

The GET and POST protocols cannot support SOAP Headers. These are required by many services for security purposes.

Additionaly, these protocols are not used that often for pure SOAP Services (as the protocol specifies the use of POST). Having them open leaves a door open that nobody will be watching. Bad people may sneak in.